# Pushing an Array into a kb.collectionObservable

Tags: jquery, html, backbone.js, knockout.js

I am wondering if I can push an array into a collection observable with specific html features. For example this is how my HTML looks as a standard:

```
  <thead class = "well">
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Reference</th>
    <th>Note</th>
    <th><button data-bind= "click: add_note" class = "btn btn-mini"><i class="icon-plus"></i></button></th>   
  </thead>   
  <tbody data-bind = "foreach: policy_notes">
    <td data-bind = "dateTimeString: date_inserted"></td>
    <td data-bind = "text: reference"></td>
    <td data-bind = "text: note"></td>
    <td></td>   
  </tbody>
```

But I want to push a new row that is an `<input>` element. I am currently pushing a new row like this:

```
add_note: function(){
  page.viewModel.policy_notes.collection().push(
    {
      date_inserted: (new Date()).toISOString(),
      reference: 'HEY!',
      note: 'HEY!'
    }
  );
},
```

But I would like reference and note to become input elements. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is what I did to solve it, Its not a very elegant solution though. I added hidden input boxes in those rows.

```
<tbody data-bind = "foreach: policy_notes">
    <td data-bind = "dateTimeString: date_inserted"></td>
    <td><span id = "ref_hide" data-bind = "text: reference"></span><input data-bind = "value: reference" type = "text" id = "ref_edit" style = "display:none; height: 10px" placeholder = "Reference"></input></td>
    <td><span id = "note_hide" data-bind = "text: note"></span><input data-bind = "value: note" type = "text" id = "note_edit" style = "display:none; height: 10px; width: 99%" placeholder = "Note"></input></td>
    <td><button data-bind = "click: save_note" id = "save_note" class = "btn btn-mini" style = "display:none"><i class="icon-ok"></i></button</td>
</tbody>
```

And simply used a jquery show and hide.

```
add_note: function(element){
  page.viewModel.policy_notes.collection().unshift(
    {
      date_inserted: (new Date()).toISOString(),
      reference: '',
      note: ''
    },
  );

  $('#note_edit').show();
  $('#note_hide').hide();

  $('#ref_edit').show();
  $('#ref_hide').hide();

  $('#save_note').show();
},
```

Is there a more elegant solution to this using jquery binds?